# Google App Script JDBC/MySql: you are not owner of thread error

Tags: mysql, jdbc, google-apps-script

I have a long query I'm trying to call from a Google App Script.
The query length is long and it takes ~20 seconds to execute.

It used to work well, but suddenly I started receiving: `statement cancelled due to timeout or client request.

Since the timeout error came immediately after `executeQuery()` was called I thought the query length was the problem, so I added it into a stored procedure.

The new query is only a call to the procedure.
Now I get the `you are not owner of thread` error, which looks like a `KILL` command sent by Google App Script for some reason.

This is my function for running the query:

```
function runQuery(query, params, isUpdate) {
  var conn = Jdbc.getConnection(dbUrl, username, password);

  var statement = conn.prepareStatement(query);
  if (params)
  {
    for (var i=0; i<params.length; i++)
    {
      var value = params[i];
      var index = i+1;    
      if (!isNaN(value))
        statement.setInt(index, parseInt(value));
      else
        statement.setString(index, value);
    }
  }
  var results = !isUpdate ? statement.executeQuery() : statement.executeUpdate();
  if (isUpdate)
    return results;
  var numCols = results.getMetaData().getColumnCount();       
  var resultsArray = processResults(results);
  results.close();
  statement.close();
  return resultsArray;
}
```

Comment: having same issue, any fix for this?

Comment: Your fix didn't solve my problem, since my query is longer than 30 seconds (which is the limit for set timeout).

Comment: If you look at the answer I posted, Google marked this as a P1 bug and working on fixing

Answer (score 1):

So it looks like Google changed the queryTimeout to 0
You can set this using setQueryTimeout on your statement and that will solve the error

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, there is an issue with the SqlStatment, as described [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/120104426)