# JDBC mySQL Error: Statement cancelled due to timeout or client request

Tags: jdbc, google-apps-script

As of today JDBC mySQL stopped working and is throwing this error:

[image]

Added timeout stmt.setQueryTimeout(30), but it does not help..

Any ideas what happened?
Is it google service?

Comment: Someone just answered this question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53518426/google-app-script-jdbc-mysql-you-are-not-owner-of-thread-error)

Comment: thanks, yes was looking at that question as well, now i see that its updated.

Answer (score 3):

Issue can be tracked directly here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/120104426
You can star it or leave comments maybe it will get priority status..

Update: google team started server rollback,  but unsure how much time it will take.. comment #28

Update2: It's working again. Tested with several queries exceeding 20k lines.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error now, the only solution is to disable V8 as described sometimes here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/120104426